# Zurb Foundation 5 data-reveal in section TAG

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, zurb-foundation, location-href

I'm trying to get work modal window in Zurb Foundation 5 on SECTION HTML tag, I get darken page without the windows, just passing the data attribute doesn't work.
This modal window works perfectly as a href="#" tag.

Is it possible to use it in common tag?

Section tag code:

```
<section class="box" onclick="window.location.href='#'" data-reveal-id="myModal-1">
```

Box:

```
<div id="myModal-1" class="reveal-modal medium">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `data-reveal` attribute in your modal dialog div, by setting it works fine.

For me work with section elements too with no problems.

Code:

```
<div id="myModal-1" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9DAPc/